# How to access IConfiguration from IHostBuiler

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, console-application, .net-6.0

I Have an Extention method for IHostBuilder

```
public static class HostBuilderConfiguration
{
    private static LoggingConfigurationOption _options;
    public static IHostBuilder CustomConfigure(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            
          _options=hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("LoggingConfigurationOption")
                .Get<LoggingConfigurationOption>();
            
        });
        // here _option is null
        return builder;


    }
}
```

In comment section,I need to `_option` but it is null

Comment: 1) Why exactly do you want to do this? 2) This is expected that options would be null because the action was not actually invoked yet.

Comment: @GuruStron, Yes I know, but i need to Configuration before build IHostBuilder

Comment: Why exactly? Can you show the use-case?

Comment: @GuruStron I need to config `Serilog `for logging Unhandle Exceptions to ELK, my ELK configuration is on the `appsettings.json` file

Comment: @GuruStron I asked my question in another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843467/configure-serilog-in-net-6-console-application

Answer (score 0):

There could be an issue if you are using `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` to build `IHostBuilder`.
The Idea can we found from this [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/81090).

> The general idea was to move away from callbacks(in CreateDefaultBuilder) and move to linear code for configuring everything, this was part of .NET 6. In .NET 7.

So it could happen the line you are trying to access _option (//here _option is null) is getting executed before, then the callback(action) inside ConfigureServices invoked(the host.build() will be called). So _option is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your ConfigureServices delegate runs later, not immediately, making _options null. To fix this, set LoggingConfigurationOption as a Singleton service within ConfigureServices, allowing it to be injected as needed in your application, rather than storing it as a static variable.

```
public static class HostBuilderConfiguration
{
    public static IHostBuilder CustomConfigure(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            var options = hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("LoggingConfigurationOption")
                .Get<LoggingConfigurationOption>();

            // Add options as a Singleton service
            services.AddSingleton(options);
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

Or you could do the following.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

        // You can access the configuration here.
        var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        string mySetting = config.GetValue<LoggingConfigurationOption>("LoggingConfigurationOption");

        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```